# Load Lines and Characteristic Curves

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

While studying electronic circuits involving diodes, I came across the concept of characteristic curve, which relates the voltage drop in a diode with the current through it. However, I was also taught about the concept of a load line, which is a plot between voltage drop and current in the diode, which is a straight line, according to the equation $v'=v-iR$, where R is the load resistance, v' is the voltage drop in the diode and v the source voltage. But, how can the same relation between diode current and voltage drop across the diode give two type of graphs? What is it that I am missing about the concept of load lines?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It's simply a graphical way to solve an equation. One line represents the left hand expression, the other represents the right. The intersection point is the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have two electrical circuits and you know the current, $i$, - voltage, $v$, characteristics of each of the circuits.

[image]

You want to find out what happens when you join the two circuits together.
After joining $v_1=v_2$ and $i_1=-i_2$.
This "joining" can be illustrated graphically as follows.

[image]

To the left there is circuit one which consists of a $750\,\rm mV$ voltage source with a $50\,\omega$ series resistor with the $i-v$ characteristic plotted below with the blue line called the *load line*.

In the middle there is circuit two which in this case happens to be a diode with  its $i-v$ characteristic plotted below.

Combining these two circuits the two graphs intersect at a point which is sometimes called the *operating point*.

Thus if the right-hand circuit is set up the voltage across the diode would be $670\,\rm mV$ and the current passing through it would be $1.6\,\rm mA$.

The operating point can be found graphically but it is a lot easier to find the solution by using an application like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-15%2F750*v%2B15+%3D+10%5E%28-11%29*%28e%5E%28v%2F26%29-1%29).

Answer (score 7):

> But, how can the same relation between diode current and voltage drop across the diode give two type of graphs?

It's not two kinds of graphs. Both graphs start with the graph of the I-V characteristic of the diode.

What's special about the load line method is that you then plot, on top of the diode characteristic, a second curve for the source characteristic. The load line is the plot of the voltage source's output current as a function of the voltage at the output terminals.

Since this is the same as the voltage across the diode, you find that the operating point of the circuit is the place where the two curves cross --- that is where, for a given terminal voltage, the output current of the source is equal to the current drawn by the diode.

Comment: But we already have the relation between diode voltage and diode current from the characteristic curve right? So are we saying that this becomes linear once we include a resistance into the circuit?

Comment: @VGovind, I assumed you're asking about a graph like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_line_(electronics)#/media/File:Load_line_diode.png). The curved line in that graph is the diode characteristic. The straight line is the source characteristic. If you are asking about a different kind of graph, please edit your question post to include the graph you are asking about.

Answer (score 5):

The diode characteristic is the relationship between the voltage drop $v'$ between the leads of the diode and the current $i$ through it. This is a functional , say $v'=f(i)$ or $i=g(v')$ relationship known from theory and/or measurement. It does not matter what is or is not connected to it, the relationship is characteristic to the diode. If now there is, say, a resistor in series with the diode, then the two share the same current so the total voltage drop between the "free" lead of the diode and the "free" lead of the resistor is $v=v'+iR=f(i)+iR = v'+g(v')R$ where $v$ is the given source voltage. Given $v$ and $R$ this is the load line for the resistor. If you also plot, say, $i=g(v')$ with the load line with $v=v'+iR$ then their intersection will get their common $i$ or $v'$ as the solution for both.

Answer (score 5):

In your circuit

[image]

you have two unknown quantities:
$i$ (the current through diode and resistor)
and $v'$ (the voltage drop in the diode).

As you said, there are two equations which both need to be satisfied:

- the current-voltage characteristic of the diode
  (given by [Shockley's diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation))
  $$i=i_S \left(e^{v'/v_T}-1\right)$$
  where $i_S$ is the reverse saturation current of the diode
  and $v_T$ is the thermal voltage ($0.025$ V at room temperature)
- and Ohm's law for the resistor
  $$i=\frac{v-v'}{R}$$

Plotting these curves it looks like this:

[image]

The fact that both equations need to be satisfied, means:
$i$ and $v'$ are no longer arbitrary, but there is only one
unique solution (the point where both curves intersect).